# Azure b2c custom email verification with SendGrid for reset password policy

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I am follow tutorial
[Custom email verification with SendGrid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-email-sendgrid), but I want to do that for reset password policy.
Everything working fine except that for `<ContentDefinition Id="api.localaccountpasswordreset">` my `<LocalizedString>` elements are not display. 
[image]
TechnicalProfile in `<UserJourney>`
[image]
[image]

And element's that are not display 
[image]
Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

You are using Display Controls to integrate Sendgrid. The correct stringIds are found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/localization-string-ids#verification-display-control-user-interface-elements).

*verification_control_but_change_claims

verification_control_fail_send_code

verification_control_fail_verify_code

verification_control_but_send_code

verification_control_but_send_new_code

verification_control_but_verify_code

verification_control_code_sen*t